# Git clone only shows "Initialized empty Git repository in what/ever/.git/"

Tags: git, web-applications

I have created a git bare repository in a remote machine, but when I try to clone it to the `/var/www/my_web_project` or any other part in the remote machine it says:

> Initialized empty Git repository in what/ever/.git/

So the repository is not cloned. It just creates the typical folders if you initialized a git repo: `branches/`, `config/`,....

I tried to clone it to my local machine just to see if the problem was the same, but I got cloned the entired project without problems.

Any idea?

Comment: What command are you using to clone the repo on the remote machine? I am not able to reproduce an "Initialized ..." message with `git clone somePath` whether the path is remote, local, existent, or nonexistent.

Comment: @cjc343 The `Initialized empty Git repository` message comes from `git init` which is called by `git clone`, and in older versions wasn't suppressed. Newer versions avoid showing that message when cloning as it tended to confuse people.

Comment: Sounds like there's no issue here then (or just an issue of an old git install)... thanks for the info.

Comment: The command being used to create the problematic clone would still be useful to know. You say that `branches` and `config` folders are created, is that underneath the `.git` directory? If not that sounds like a bare repository is being created. What output do you get if you run `git status` within the problematic clone?

Comment: @qqx i updated ubuntu on my remote machine and now clone works, thanks!